# how to make light map for an object that has multiple materials?

Tags: materials, uv, lighting

Id searched ways to generate lightmap for an object that has multiple materials with each different textures, but most of things that i found is seperating object by materials or one object with one materials. Is there any way to generate light map for an object that has multiple materials?  Thank you.

Comment: Create one material, one UV map that would contain UVs for all the surfaces of the object and bake whatever you want then use the same baked map with the same UV map for whatever number of materials you want on the object. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Does this work on object that already has uv map and multiple materials?

Comment: If the UVs are suitable for baking - not overlapping and inside (0,0) - (1,1) square in UV space. So this might not be what you use for some of your materials, but you can create multiple UV maps for one object so it might make sense to have a separate UV map for light baking.